# Convert string to multiple arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a comma separated string and i want to convert it into multiple arrays. Here is the code i tried but failed to achieve the expected output.

```
const data = "123,456";
result = data.split(',').map(s => Array.from(s));

console.log(result); // [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]
```

Expected output:

```
[["123"], ["456"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map it to an array.

```js
const data = "123,456";
result = data.split(',').map(s => [s]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As epascarello suggests on his comment, try

```
data.split(',').map(s =>[s]);
```

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for more info!